# catkin_make vs catkin build

Tags: ros, moveit, catkin-make, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was reading about the moveit package and I tried to install from source. My problem was that the catkin build command didn't work. So I did apt-get install catkin_tools and then I was able to install the moveit package.

Then I cloned another package in my workspace and ran catkin_make but it didn't work. This is the error I'm getting :

```
Built target moveit_robot_interaction
[ 80%] Built target moveit_move_group_capabilities_base 
make[2]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir                    /src/planning_scene_storage.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit /warehouse/planning_scene_world_storage.h:40:0,
             from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/src/planning_scene_world_storage.cpp:37:
/home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit/warehouse    /moveit_message_storage.h:40:47: fatal error: warehouse_ros/database_connection.h: No such file or directory
 #include <warehouse_ros/database_connection.h>
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit   /warehouse/constraints_storage.h:40:0,
                 from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse /src/constraints_storage.cpp:37:
/home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit/warehouse    /moveit_message_storage.h:40:47: fatal error: warehouse_ros/database_connection.h: No such file or directory
#include <warehouse_ros/database_connection.h>
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
[ 80%] make[2]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir /src/moveit_message_storage.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit /warehouse/trajectory_constraints_storage.h:40:0,
                 from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse    /src/trajectory_constraints_storage.cpp:37:
/home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit/warehouse   /moveit_message_storage.h:40:47: fatal error: warehouse_ros/database_connection.h: No such file or directory
#include <warehouse_ros/database_connection.h>
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
Building CXX object moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir    /src/state_storage.cpp.o
make[2]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir /src/planning_scene_world_storage.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit/warehouse/state_storage.h:40:0,
             from /home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/src/state_storage.cpp:37:
/home/sbr/first_workspace/src/moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/include/moveit/warehouse/moveit_message_storage.h:40:47: fatal error: warehouse_ros/database_connection.h: No such file or directory
 #include <warehouse_ros/database_connection.h>
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir/src/constraints_storage.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir/src/trajectory_constraints_storage.cpp.o] Error 1
[ 80%] Built target move_group
make[2]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir/src/state_storage.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/warehouse/warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 83%] Built target moveit_ompl_interface
[ 84%] Built target moveit_pick_place_planner
[ 85%] Built target moveit_move_group_default_capabilities 
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

What is the issue in using catkin_make and catkin build simultaneously?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243192/catkin_make-vs-catkin-build/) by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-06**:
They may overwrite each other's `devel/setup.bash` script

**Comment by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on 2016-09-08**:
So if I am building a workspace with catkin build, I should never use that workspace to host other packages and run catkin_make to build those packages, right?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-08**:
I think so. The `catkin build` command is like a more modern `catkin_make` I've migrated to that (meaning `catkin_tools`) completely. See http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not combine the two build tools in the same workspace at the same time. Their build artifacts are incompatible.

If you run `catkin config`, it will tell you which toolset is currently in use. If you wish to switch to catkin build, run `catkin clean -bdy` first.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really want to maintain all spaces (i.e. build and devel) at the same time using [catkin command-line tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the default catkin tools (e.g. `catkin_make`), you can change the default names of the folders associated with the spaces using the following command:

```
catkin config --space-suffix _cb
```

After you type and execute the command `catkin build`, the folders `build_cb`, `devel_cb` and `logs_cb` (instead of respectively `build` and `devel`) will be created.

Now, you can also build the workspace using `catkin_make` and the folders `build` and `devel` will also be created. So, after the two builds (one with the catkin command-line tools and the other with catkin default tools), you should have the following folders:

1. build
2. build_cb
3. devel
4. devel_cb
5. logs_cb
6. src

You can clean the folders associated with `catkin build` using `catkin clean`. After `catkin clean`, you still have the folders generated by `catkin_make`. Furthermore, you need to execute `catkin config --space-suffix _cb` only once.

See also: https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html.

---

Originally posted by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) with karma: 372 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2